# How to inspect the type of argument that function A will call passed in function B with in C++ 14

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have the following code.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main () {

    // A function that when passed another
    // function will call it with a value.
    // In this case tap calls out with (int)10. 
    auto tap = [](auto out){
        out(10);     
    };

    // A function that when passed a tap shaped function will
    // collect all values from the tap and
    // add them to the vector.
    auto toVector = [](auto && tap){
        using T = int;
        std::vector<T> out;
        tap([&](auto const & i){ out.push_back(i);});
        return out;
    };
 

    // Using generic toVector collect all results from the specific ``tap`` function above
    auto vec = toVector(tap);

    std::cerr << vec[0] << std::endl;
}
```

The problem with the above is that `toVector` is not generic. I need the line

```
using T = int
```

to make it work.

Is it possible to change `toVector` to be fully generic by something like

```
    // A function that when passed a tap will
    // collect all values from the tap and
    // add them to the vector.
    auto toVector = [](auto && tap){
        using T = Tap<tap>::type;
        std::vector<T> out;
        tap([&](auto const & i){ out.push_back(i);});
        return out;
    };
```

where `Tap<T>::type` is the magic meta function yet to be discovered.

Comment: Your `tap` lambda isn't SFINAE so I don't think there's any template metaprogramming you can do to infer the callback parameter type.

Comment: `T` depends on `tap` **and** `out`, `tap([&](auto i){ out.push_back(std::to_string(i)); })` would require `T=std::string`...

Comment: There is no standard type trait that allows you to inspect the *body* of a (member) function so as to determine what you want. If tap was defined to `-> decltype(auto) { return out(10); }` - then you could perhaps leverage `std::invoke_result` with an appropriate functor.

Comment: how about passing `tag`: `toVector(tag<int>{}, tap);` (or make the function template to have `toVector<int>(tap);`)?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I see your point. There is no way to unravel this. I have got myself stuck in what I thought was some elegant code. The greater library is here https://godbolt.org/z/KbeKhx I realized I couldn't add a combinator ``toVector`` without specificying ``toVector<int>`` as there was no simple way to extract the element type from the pipeline. The above is a simplified statement of the problem.